# Can't get counter to compare first letter of word against A-Z alphabet

Tags: python-2.7, string-comparison, word-count

What I'm trying to do is compare the first letter of each word against the 
lower case a-z alphabet and print (similar to the word_frequency) how many
times a word starts with each letter of the alphabet
(such as this)

```
a = 0 b = 2, c = 0, d = 2 ------------ y = 1, z = 0
```

but I am unable to find a way to do this through Counter as of yet or found anything that worked for me (beginner). The idea I had was something along the lines of

```
    for w in word_count:
        l_freq = []
        l_freq.append(w[0])
```

and then comparing the counter against it? but not sure how to compare against the whole alphabet rather than just the letters in the string?

Also, is there any way to print the frequency cleaner? Without Counter and brackets showing up?

```
from collections import Counter

def function():
    string = "This is a string written in python."
    word_count = string.split()

    char_count = 0

    for char in string:
        if char != " " and char != ".":
            char_count += 1

    word_freq = Counter(word_count)

    print "Word count:  " + str(len(word_count))
    print "Average length of word: " + str(char_count / len(word_count))
    print ""
    print "Word frequency: "
    print word_freq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have some test data like this:

```
In [1]: test_data = '''
   ...: hello
   ...: hi
   ...: goodbye
   ...: bye
   ...: Bye!
   ...: lol
   ...: lmao
   ...: rofl
   ...: '''
```

To count the first letter of each word, you'd do this:

```
counter = Counter(w[0] for w in test_data.split())
```

which you're basically doing. To get the expected output I *think* you want, you just need to associate each lowercase letter with its count, like so (`import string` if you haven't already):

```
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print letter, '=', counter[letter]
```

Which for the test data I showed gives you:

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 1
h = 2
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
l = 2
m = 0
n = 0
o = 0
p = 0
q = 0
r = 1
s = 0
t = 0
u = 0
v = 0
w = 0
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your quick response will try out now and if it works will mark as solution right away!